# Trying to take values of theta and print them out into radians

Tags: python

This is an intro level coding course in python so PLEASE go easy on the terminology as we are just taking baby steps. Here is my for loop that I am trying to work.

```
g=9.81
h0=1
radians=pi*thetas(j)/180
distances=range(31)
hvals=range(31)
thetas=[5,10,15,20,25,35,45,55,65,75,85]
for j,k in enumerate(thetas):
    print j,k

xvals=range(31)
xvals=[0.1*x for x in xvals]
for i,v in enumerate(xvals):
    print i,v

for j=0 to k:
    radians=pi*thetas(j)/180
    print radians
```

Now what I am essentially trying to do here is have this for loop run through the values of the list "thetas" and then print them out in a list. Can someone help me out here a bit? Thanks!

Comment: what is your problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your syntax is wrong

```
for j=0 to k:  # this isn't how you iterate over a range
    radians=pi*thetas(j)/180  # need to use [] instead of () to index a list
    print radians
```

The correct syntax for this would be

```
pi = 3.14

for j in range(len(thetas)):
    radians=pi*thetas[j]/180.0
    print radians
```

Or you can skip indexing all together

```
for angle in thetas:
    radians = pi * angle / 180.0
    print radians
```

Or you can do the whole thing in a list comprehension

```
radians = [pi * angle / 180.0 for angle in thetas]
```

Comment: Ok so I coded that up and here is what I got in return.             
  File "C:/Users/Student/Desktop/Python Coding/Physics code assignment 1.py", line 17, in <module>
    radians=pi*thetas(j)/180

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Square brackets for indexing. Parentheses for function calling. Note the answer has square brackets: [ ]

Comment: Got it all fixed! Thanks for help Cyber and Max!